# Find div by contents

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have the following row of divs:

```
<div class="current-task"><div class="text-task"><h2 id="title-task">wee</h2><h5 id="time-inserted">You, 2020/12/19 3:26:02 PM</h5><p id="task-content">lkjs</p></div></div>
<div class="current-task"><div class="text-task"><h2 id="title-task">lee</h2><h5 id="time-inserted">You, 2020/12/25 3:14:15 PM</h5><p id="task-content">abcd</p></div></div> // the one I want to find
```

What I want to find is the div which contains h2: "lee", p: "abcd", and h5: "You, 2020/12/25 3:14:15 PM", and which order it is in (first one with class "current task" = 0, second = 1, and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var currentTasks = document.getElementsByClassName("current-task");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < currentTasks.length; i++){
  var h2 = currentTasks[i].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].textContent;
  var p = currentTasks[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent;
  var h5 = currentTasks[i].getElementsByTagName("h5")[0].textContent;
  if(h2=="lee"&&p=="abcd"&&h5=="You, 2020/12/25 3:14:15 PM"){
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="current-task"><div class="text-task"><h2 id="title-task">wee</h2><h5 id="time-inserted">You, 2020/12/19 3:26:02 PM</h5><p id="task-content">lkjs</p></div></div>
<div class="current-task"><div class="text-task"><h2 id="title-task">lee</h2><h5 id="time-inserted">You, 2020/12/25 3:14:15 PM</h5><p id="task-content">abcd</p></div></div>
```